# Why does my c function translate() returns random symbols?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a Atbash Translator, Atbash is just the alphabet backwards. For example A would equal Z. But the translate() function only returns random letters or symbol.

I'm not sure if the problem is with my logic in reassigning the values. The variable reverse should have the value of the atbash of the matched letter.

```
char translate(char text){
    char letter;
    char reverse;
    letter  = text;
    char alphabet[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char atbash[26] = {'Z','Y', 'X', 'W', 'V', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'};
    int x = 0;
    int size = 26;

    while(x <= size)
     {
        if(letter == alphabet[x])
            {
               reverse = atbash[x];
               break;
            }
        x++;        
     }
    return reverse;
}

int main(){
    char text [100];
    char translation [100];
    int strSize, i;

    printf("Hi! this is ATBASH translator.\n");
    printf("Use CAPSLOCK to input text\n");

    printf("ENTER TEXT: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", text);

    strSize = strlen(text); //I removed the minus 1 
for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++){
    translation[i] = translate(text[i]);
}
    printf("TRANSLATION: %s", translation);
    return 0;
}
```

I figured it out!! thanks guys! 
I deducted the size of the string "text" that's why I wasn't able to get the last char.

UPDATE: i did not figured it out yet (i thought i figured it out lol)

I typed ABC and it returned ZYX, but when I typed ABCDE it outputs ZYXWV (which is right) but along with it are the random characters again. It's like this:

```
ENTER TEXT: ABCDE
TRANSLATION: ZYXWVy`~?.|
```

Comment: In `translate()` the var `letter` is uninitialized. You probably meant to use `text`. Typo.

Comment: Side note: you don't null terminate `translation`.

Comment: There's no need to use arrays. Just use `reverse = 'Z' - (letter - 'A');`

Comment: You need to enable compiler warnings. What compiler are you using? (If it's gcc, `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2` is a good start.)

Comment: Note that `strSize` skips the last letter in the input.  You don't need the `- 1` here.

Comment: @Barmar Not in EBCDIC!

Comment: @ melpomene 
-------------- Build: Debug in reverse (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is issue with your comparing logic. Updated one is this.

```
char translate(char text){
    char letter;
    char reverse;
    letter  = text;
    char alphabet[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char atbash[26] = {'Z','Y', 'X', 'W', 'V', 'U', 'T', 'S', 'R', 'Q', 'P', 'O', 'N', 'M', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'};
    int x = 0;
    int size = 26;

    while(x <= size)
     {
        if(letter == alphabet[x])
            {
               reverse = atbash[x];
               break;
            }
        x++;        
     }
    return reverse;
}
```

Comment: thanks! IT'S WORKING, but the last letter always turns out to be random letters and symbols.

Comment: an example or screenshot will be helpful

Comment: I think changing to `while (x < size)` should fix the last random letter (there are 26 elements in the array, so x must be 0 .. 25)

Comment: @Vaibhav can't attach screenshots yet because i don't have reputations yet haha

Comment: @schnaader already tried it but it all turns out to output the same result. I can't seem to get the last char

Comment: @schnaader haha thanks! I figured it out after replying to you "I can't seem to get the last char". The problem was with my algorithm in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

You are Sending text, but text is never used

Comment: Don't waste time answering trivial typo questions like this, they should just be closed.

Answer (score 0):

the letter variable in function is used but never initialized